# Is it possible to derive a and b by brute force attack on the Diffie-Hellman protocol?

Tags: security, cryptography, diffie-hellman

Say, if a and/or b were small numbers, and I came to know e(a) and e(b), how would I go about deriving a and b? My lecturer was teaching this concept in the class, but I didn't particularly understand the algorithm behind deriving a and b? He said something like you try and find out which of the a or b is a smaller value and then once you have figured it out, you can figure out a or b in a more efficient time? How would I find out which one of e(a) or e(b) comes from a smaller value a or b in the first place and if I did how would I use that to actually calculate a or b? What is the algorithm behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about which is smaller, you will find which one is smaller via brute force.

The trivial brute force attack is compute e(x) for x=1, 2, 3, ... and checking whether it matches e(a) or e(b).  This is O(min(a,b)).

There is a faster algorithm that involves [kangaroos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_kangaroo_algorithm).  It's running time is square root of the brute force.